# Does there exist a finite-volume hyperbolic Coxeter polytope with these properties?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, convex-polytopes, hyperbolic-geometry, coxeter-groups, polytopes

I searched for a finite-volume, hyperbolic Coxeter polytope of dimension $n \geq 4$ with the following properties $a$ and $b$.

$a$) It has exactly one ideal vertex;

$b$) if a bounded facet and an unbounded facet intersect, then their dihedral angle is an even submultiple of $\pi$.

On Anna Felikson's website I found exactly one of such a polytope. It has dimension $n=4$ and the link of the ideal vertex is a prism over a $(2,4,4)$-triangle.

By doubling the polytope, I can easily find other polytopes that satisfy the desired properties whose link of the ideal vertex is a parallelepiped.

Is there any polytope with the desired properties with dimension $n>4$? Is there any polytope with the desired properties with dimension $n=4$, whose link of the ideal vertex is not a parallelepiped nor a prism over a $(2,4,4)$-triangle?